# Find angle of head tilt from ARFaceAnchor in an ARFaceTracking session

Tags: ios, scenekit, ios11, arkit, iphone-x

I am trying to find the angle of the head with regards to the y axis in a `ARFaceAnchor`. My starting example is Apple's sample code: [creating face-based AR experiences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences).

Given this image, I am basically searching for the angle of the green marker (from the `coordinateOrigin` node) relative to the vertical axis.

[image]

The `ARFaceAnchor` object inherits from `ARAnchor` `, providing a`transform` property:

> A matrix encoding the position, orientation, and scale of the anchor
>   relative to the world coordinate space of the AR session the anchor is
>   placed in.

The type of such `transform` is as follows:
`var transform: matrix_float4x4 { get }`

How do I derive angle information such as the one described from this matrix?

Comment: you might have solved that one right? I just asked a similar question, i.e. how to get euler angles directly from ARFaceAnchor ?

Comment: sorry I still don't know the answer @DavidThery

Comment: I think I have solved it in the meantime, see here if interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082908/extract-yaw-pitch-roll-from-faceanchor-in-arkit/66092737#66092737

Answer (score 2):

As Apple does not provide a quaternion to euler conversion for this class, in my case I had to compute them by hand as shown below.

Please find the reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082908/extract-yaw-pitch-roll-from-faceanchor-in-arkit/66092737#66092737), which is inspired by [this mathematical resource](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm).

```
extension matrix_float4x4 {
   // Function to convert rad to deg
   func radiansToDegress(radians: Float32) -> Float32 {
       return radians * 180 / (Float32.pi)
   }
   var translation: SCNVector3 {
      get {
          return SCNVector3Make(columns.3.x, columns.3.y, columns.3.z)
      }
   }
   // Retrieve euler angles from a quaternion matrix
   var eulerAngles: SCNVector3 {
       get {
           // Get quaternions
           // http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm
           let qw = sqrt(1 + self.columns.0.x + self.columns.1.y + self.columns.2.z) / 2.0
           let qx = (self.columns.2.y - self.columns.1.z) / (qw * 4.0)
           let qy = (self.columns.0.z - self.columns.2.x) / (qw * 4.0)
           let qz = (self.columns.1.x - self.columns.0.y) / (qw * 4.0)

           // Deduce euler angles with some cosines
           // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles
           /// yaw (z-axis rotation)
           let siny = +2.0 * (qw * qz + qx * qy)
           let cosy = +1.0 - 2.0 * (qy * qy + qz * qz)
           let yaw = radiansToDegress(radians:atan2(siny, cosy))
           // pitch (y-axis rotation)
           let sinp = +2.0 * (qw * qy - qz * qx)
           var pitch: Float
           if abs(sinp) >= 1 {
               pitch = radiansToDegress(radians:copysign(Float.pi / 2, sinp))
           } else {
               pitch = radiansToDegress(radians:asin(sinp))
           }
           /// roll (x-axis rotation)
           let sinr = +2.0 * (qw * qx + qy * qz)
           let cosr = +1.0 - 2.0 * (qx * qx + qy * qy)
           let roll = radiansToDegress(radians:atan2(sinr, cosr))
           
           /// return array containing ypr values
           return SCNVector3(yaw, pitch, roll)
           }
   }
}
```